# Jenkins avoid tool installation if it is installed already

Tags: jenkins

Not a jenkins expert here. I have a scripted pipeline where I have tool installed (Node). Unfortunately it was configured to pull in other dependencies which takes 250sec in overall now.  I'd like to add a condition to avoid this installation if it(Node with packages) was already installed previously, but don't know where to start. Perhaps jenkins stores meta info from prev runs that can be checked?

```
node {
  env.NODEJS_HOME = "${tool 'Node v8.11.3'}"
  env.PATH = "${env.NODEJS_HOME}/bin:${env.PATH}"
  env.PATH = "/opt/xs/bin:${env.PATH}"
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using dynamic jenkins agents (docker containers)? In this case tools will be installed everytime you run build.
Mount volumes to containers, use persistant agents or build your own docker image with installed nodejs.

As I see you use workaround to install nodejs tool.

Jenkins supports it native way (declarative style):

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {
        nodejs 'NodeJS_14.5'
    }
    stages {
        stage ('nodejs test') {
            steps {
                sh 'npm -v'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On first run tools will be installed. On next ones - will not since it is installed.

Comment: thanks for the answer, we use scripted pipeline not a declarative one